# Elixir - find sub-bitstring within larger bitstring

Tags: testing, erlang, substring, bitstring, elixir

How would I go about finding if a sub-bitstring is present with another bitstring in Elixir? I need to verify that bitstring X exists somewhere within bitstring Y for testing purposes. Is there a simple way to do this with existing functions?

```
x = "bar"
y = "foo bar baz"
some_substring_function(x, y)
```

with `some_substring_function` returning a truthy value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `=~` operator:

```
iex> "hello world" =~ "hello"
true
```

The [String module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html) also has some convenience functions.

Comment: This may be obvious to non-newbies, but the `=~` operator only works on binaries (i.e., bitstrings whose number of bits is divisible by 8). So, this works: `<<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>> =~ <<1, 2, 3>>`, but this gives you an invalid argument error: `<<0::size(9)>> =~ <<0>>`