# Elixir bitstring contains sub-bitstring

Tags: elixir

I'd like to check whether a long bitstring contains another bitstring within it. Something like:

```
if MyBitstringModule.contains(<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>, <<2, 3, 4>>) do
  # do stuff
end
```

If I had *binaries* instead, this would be really easy: I could use [the `=~` operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#=~/2) or [String.contains?/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#contains?/2). However, both of those operate on binaries only and would therefore fail on bitstrings whose size is not divisible by 8.

The best I've come up with so far is a recursive pattern match like this (not actually working!), which seems like a kludge:

```
def contains(haystack, needle) when is_bitstring(haystack) and is_bitstring(needle) do
  needle_size = bit_size(needle)
  case haystack do
    <<>> -> false
    <<^needle::size(needle_size), _::bitstring>> -> true
    <<_::size(1), remainder::bitstring>> -> contains(remainder, needle)
  end
end
```

[Note that despite having more or less the same title, this is not actually a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636547/elixir-find-sub-bitstring-within-larger-bitstring)—the linked question and its answer both deal with *binaries* only.]

EDIT: My test case above was bad, since both arguments are actually binaries. Better test cases are:

```
iex> contains(<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1::size(1)>>, <<2, 3, 4>>)
true
iex> contains(<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1::size(1)>>, <<4, 5, 1::size(1)>>)
true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me adding the `bitstring` type to your true case

```rb
<<^needle::bitstring-size(needle_size), _::bitstring>> -> true
```

If you try matching on it directly

```rb
iex> needle = <<3, 4, 5>>
<<3, 4, 5>>
iex> needle_size = bit_size(needle)
24
iex> <<^needle::size(needle_size), _::bitstring>> = <<3, 4, 5>>
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: <<3, 4, 5>>
iex> <<^needle::bitstring-size(needle_size), _::bitstring>> = <<3, 4, 5>>
<<3, 4, 5>>
```